# How to prvent visiting the page after logout?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET and C#.After click logout i am using this.

```
Session.Abandon();
Session.RemoveAll();
Page.Responce.Cache.setCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
```

But after this if they clicked back button in browser it is going to previous page.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Thanks..

**Edit:**

I did used this.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Session["LoginId"] == null)
            Response.Redirect("frmLogin.aspx");
        else
        {
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
            Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        }
    }
}
```

Because of this they click browser back button then the pageload will be called so there we can check for the session variable for authentication.

Comment: what is your authentication mode?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488548(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am posting a link I hope this guide you and Help you whatever you need click here

[http://www.dotnetfunda.com/](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/code1651-prevent-back-button-after-logout-in-aspnet.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

```
            if (Session["Navigation"] == null)
            {
                Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
                Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
            }                                                                               protected void lnkbtnLogOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Session["Navigation"] = null;
        Session.Abandon();

        Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
    }                                                                                             but it's not working.It still redirects to prevoios page after click on back button
```

Answer (score 0):

set page attribute `<outputcache=none>`

Comment: I am using windows authenticaion mode.

Comment: yes so put above attribute on pages would help you solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Following would serve your way:

The code disable the cache in browser.

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Or

You may add script to delete history on browser, after the logout.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"cle","windows.history.clear",true);
```

Hope either of above two would work.

---

You may check for the `Session["---"]` variable availability, if Session is not available then redirect user to Login/Register page.

What I mean to say is, you are Abandoning the session, this might destroy Session variables. So when user click on back button, System will check for Session, it would not found that and user will be redirected to Login/Register page.

If you are using built-in membership classes for user management, then user [Authorize] attribute. This may prevent user visiting page after logout, and redirect unregistered user to Login/Register page.

Comment: but while clicking back button it wont call pageload event.

Comment: Your browser might have cached the earlier copy. Just clear your browser history, then run application and give the result, it works or not.