# How to clear browser history oan clear cache?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a login page and a home page. Users can log in from the login page to the home page using a username and password. What I want to achieve is:

**1) When user log out from home page, he/she should not be "logged in" by clicking the *back* or *forward* button in the browser.**

**2) It is sure that the browser will store a history of the home page. But when the user click on the history link in the home page available in the browser, it should be redirected to the login page instead of the home page.**

I have tried clearing the cache by using the following code in page_load event in the home page:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
```

But it is still not working. Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use follwing code in OnPrerender() event of home page . It worked for me.

```
  protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreRender(e);
            string sb;
            sb = "<script language=javascript>\n";
            sb += "window.history.forward(1);\n";
            sb += "\n</script>";
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "clientScript", sb);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

How are you storing the login? if you are using session variables you could clear the session when user logs out and then on every page that you need to have the user logged in to view check to make sure that session variable exists in the page load, if it does then let the user continue and if not redirect to the login page (you could do this quickly by using a master page)

if you are using a cookie to store the log in then you could just expire the cookie when the user logs out

Comment: i'm using javascript to pass the values of password and username as query string

Comment: This is really not a secure way to deal with logins even if you encode the urls and I would advice you switch to a server side process, and as a user I know I would not be happy with a website editing content on my computer which is what your question is trying to do (just my two cents for what its worth)

Answer (score -1):

I have solution for You Please Find link below

Hope You will get your answer

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542760/how-to-prvent-visiting-the-page-after-logout/12543044#12543044)

or

also find from this [DotnetFundaa](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/code1651-prevent-back-button-after-logout-in-aspnet.aspx)

On Page Load Put Code of below

```
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score -1):

when the user logins,keep his userid or whatever unique id the user has.And when he clicks logout unset the userid session..And add a few line in you page

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['uid']=$uid;
if($uid=='')
{
header("location:loginpage.php");
}
?>
```

It'll work.

Comment: Maybe it work oh php, but here is asking for asp.net solution